# Одно слово для значения "свернулся в клубок"

Tags: словообразование

Можно ли образовать такое? Если да, то какой вид оно примет? Скомкался, скомочился, склубился, оклубился?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самым близким к исходному выражению является глагол "склубиться" со значением "сгуститься, приняв округлую форму". Придать этому слову значение "свернуться в клубок" можно только в очень смелом авторском варианте, что-о вроде "кот склубился на диване".

ПРИМЕРЫ

Но вдруг дунул ветер ― тучи сдвинулись, склубились и полетели, расторгаясь о зубчатые верхи.

Будто клещами холодными сердце сжато, и в горле склубились безотчетные слезы.

Пастернак умер, когда вокруг него склубилось зло, сгустились отрицательные, черные эмоции и силы.

Comment: Я полагаю, лучше будет использовать "сжался" (в значение "весь сжался"). Как-то более ёмче и конкретней.

Comment: Да, лучше: сжался. Но в том случае, если речь идет о живых существах.

Comment: Нашёл безупречное слово: съёжился!

Comment: Великолепно!

Answer (score 2):

У нас в семье есть окказионализм "склубочиться" для внутреннего пользования, как раз о котах. "Съежиться" - это от какого-то дискомфорта, а свернуться клубочком - это усатым-хвостатым явно нравится.;)

Comment: Симпатичное слово: клубок - склубочиться, грамматика правильная, формант С...И(ТЬ)СЯ. Значение - проявить то, что названо мотивирующим существительным. Кстати, слово "скорчиться" имеет похожее значение: кора - корка - скорчиться. И.-е. корень sker - резать, кора - это то, что отрезано (родственные слова: скорняк, короткий и др.) и имеет изогнутую форму.

Comment: "Проявить"?.. Ох, не знаю... не содержится клубка в коте, или ежа (см. выше). Может, все-таки "уподобиться, стать похожим"?

За напоминание про "скорняка" отдельное спасибо (хорошо бы еще источник цитирования, поскольку это НЕ общеизвестный Фасмер ;)).

Comment: Уподобиться - это частный случай проявления признака, я же приводила общую формулировку. Съежиться - это стать похожим на ежа.